# Installing perl dependency automatically in perl

Tags: perl, installation

I'm very new to perl. I wish I could install some package from perl, I did so like this :

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install VM::EC2'
```

Its getting failed due to dependency I guess, it shows :

```
Result: FAIL
Failed 8/8 test programs. 9/9 subtests failed.
  LDS/VM-EC2-1.20.tar.gz
one dependency not OK (XML::Simple); additionally test harness failed
  ./Build test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports LDS/VM-EC2-1.20.tar.gz
Running Build install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

In this case how do I ask perl to install `XML::Simple` and other depedency automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Method 1: Using cpanm**

You can either use [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/module/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.5019/bin/cpanm) and then use `cpanm modulename` command.

```
cpanm VM::EC2
```

The above command will install VM::EC2 module with all its dependencies automatically.

**Method 2: Changing configuration of CPAN**

or you can tell CPAN directly

```
$ perl -MCPAN -e shell
cpan[1]>  o conf prerequisites_policy follow
cpan[2]>  o conf commit
exit
```

The first line sets your dependency policy to follow rather than ask (the default). The second line tells CPAN to write the changes to your user's CPAN configuration file to make them permanent.

So the next time you try to install Perl module from CPAN shell, it will install all its dependencies without prompting you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [cpanm](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.5019/bin/cpanm):

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'App::cpanminus'
```

and then

```
cpanm VM::EC2
```

look at the documentation for other features.