# Installing koha by cpan, Can't locate XML/LibXSLT.pm

Tags: perl

The following fatal error has occurred:

> Can't locate XML/LibXSLT.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
>   /home/koha/koha/koha /etc/perl
>
> /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5
>   /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14
>   /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /home/koha/koha/koha/C4/XSLT.pm line
>   28. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/koha/koha/koha/C4/XSLT.pm line 28. Compilation failed in require
>   at /home/koha/koha/koha/C4/Search.pm line 28. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at /home/koha/koha/koha/C4/Search.pm line
>   28. Compilation failed in require at /home/koha/koha/koha/C4/Heading.pm line 25. BEGIN failed--compilation
>   aborted at /home/koha/koha/koha/C4/Heading.pm line 25. Compilation
>   failed in require at /home/koha/koha/koha/C4/Biblio.pm line 36.
>   Compilation failed in require at /home/koha/koha/koha/C4/Reserves.pm
>   line 26. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
>   /home/koha/koha/koha/C4/Reserves.pm line 26. Compilation failed in
>   require at /home/koha/koha/koha/C4/Circulation.pm line 25. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at /home/koha/koha/koha/C4/Circulation.pm
>   line 25. Compilation failed in require at
>   /home/koha/koha/koha/C4/Overdues.pm line 25. BEGIN failed--compilation
>   aborted at /home/koha/koha/koha/C4``/Overdues.pm line 25. Compilation
>   failed in require at /home/koha/koha/koha/C4/Members.pm line 27. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at /home/koha/koha/koha/C4/Members.pm line
>   27. Compilation failed in require at /home/koha/koha/koha/C4/Auth.pm line 27. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
>   /home/koha/koha/koha/C4/Auth.pm line 27. Compilation failed in require
>   at /home/koha/koha/koha/opac/opac-main.pl line 22. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at /home/koha/koha/koha/opac/opac-main.pl
>   line 22.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the [**XML::LibXSLT**](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXSLT) module.

Install it by:

```
$ cpan XML::LibXSLT
```

Also check: [Installing perl dependency automatically in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066907/installing-perl-dependency-automatically-in-perl/14067234#14067234)

Have a look at [**Bundle::KohaSupport**](http://search.cpan.org/~koha/Bundle-KohaSupport-0.31/lib/Bundle/KohaSupport.pm) - A bundle of the required Perl modules for Koha Intergrated Library System.