# Not able to use Net::SFTP module in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, net-sftp

I am using perl, v5.10.1 on my Linux Ubuntu machine. I tried to install `Net::SFTP` module through `cpan` prompt but its giving the below errors for past 2 days.

warning:

```
Warning: no success downloading
'/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp19821'. Giving up on
it. at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/Index.pm line 225
```

error:

```
Connecting to www.perl.org|207.171.7.51|:80... failed: Connection
timed out.

Connecting to www.perl.org|207.171.7.41|:80... failed: Connection
timed out.
```

Then I installed it by tar file method through CPAN site. now when I run the below sample script its throwing me the error.

script:

```
use Net::SFTP;

my $host = "169.144.106.231";
my %args = ( 
        user => "root",
        password => "******" );

my $sftp = Net::SFTP->new($host, %args);
```

Error:

```
Can't locate Net/SSH/Perl/Buffer.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /usr/local/share/perl5/Net/SFTP/Buffer.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl5/Net/SFTP/Buffer.pm line 6.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl5/Net/SFTP/Attributes.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl5/Net/SFTP/Attributes.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl5/Net/SFTP.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl5/Net/SFTP.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at ankur_sftp.pl line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ankur_sftp.pl line 6.
```

I don't have `Net/SSH/Perl/Buffer.pm` installed and few modules like `Buffer.pm` are residing at some other path.

```
/root/Net-SFTP-0.10/blib/lib/Net/SFTP/Buffer.pm
/root/Net-SFTP-0.10/lib/Net/SFTP/Buffer.pm
```

My `@INC` contains

```
/usr/local/lib64/perl5
/usr/local/share/perl5
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
usr/lib64/perl5
/usr/share/perl5
```

Can anyone please help here? Why is `cpan` prompt method is throwing that error? Next for tar file method if there is module dependency issue then how to resolve it using CPAN tar file method? Also how to install the modules on the correct path because I don't want to add all the required module's paths in `@INC` path in the beginning of my script. I am a root user here.

Comment: You haven't properly installed the Net::SFTP module. Fix the problem that is preventing CPAN from working, then use it.

Comment: use [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign) that is available in Ubuntu as libnet-sftp-foreign-perl. It also provides a compatibility API (Net::SFTP::Foreign::Compat) that mimics Net::SFTP one.

Answer (score 3):

> Can't locate Net/SSH/Perl/Buffer.pm

That means the `Net::SSH::Perl::Buffer` module is missing. You need to install it.

Net/SFTP/Buffer.pm is not same as Net::SSH::Perl::Buffer.

You're facing the dependency issue, either you will have to go to CPAN and download tar file and install module, and you will have to do this for each missing module. I would suggest you to try CPAN client, or App::cpanminus so that the dependencies can be installed automatically.

For that see this: [Installing perl dependency automatically in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066907/installing-perl-dependency-automatically-in-perl/14067234#14067234)

> I don't want to add all the required module's paths in @INC path in
>   the beginning of my script

Then make sure the `@INC` contains the path where your modules are getting installed. You can tell it by

`export PERL5LIB=/home/foobar/code` (For Linux) (Add this to `~/.bashrc` to make it always available when you log-in.)

`set PERL5LIB = c:\path\to\dir` (For Windows)

Comment: Thanks....I did what u told..My @INC contains required paths now (/roo/Net-SSH-Perl-1.37/blib/lib & /root/Net-SFTP-0.10/blib/lib) but it is still showing the error. –
           BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/Net-SSH-Perl-1.37/blib/lib/Net/SSH/Perl/Util/SSH2MP.pm line 6.
          Compilation failed in require at /root/Net-SSH-Perl-1.37/blib/lib/Net/SSH/Perl/Util.pm line 56.
           and lots more for other modules...

Comment: Check the line where it is giving error. I think there will be a require/use line for a module, which will be missing. So you need to install that also.