# Installing cURL modules for Perl on Windows

Tags: perl, curl, installation, libcurl, perl-module

I have [ActivePerl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActivePerl) 5.14.2 on my Windows machine. I have been trying to install the LWP cURL module. I have already installed the libcurl-dev library and GCC on my machine.

I also understand that LWP cURL has a dependency on the WWW-Curl-Easy module. So I installed that too. I installed all these through the command lines using the steps given in the Readme files. I ran the `perl makefile.pl` command followed by a `make` and a `make install`. No errors were given out during the installation.

I am trying to execute this sample code to test my LWP cURL installation:

```
    use LWP::Curl;
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my $lwpcurl = LWP::Curl->new();
    my $content = $lwpcurl->get('http://search.cpan.org','http://www.cpan.org');
```

I am receiving the below error:

> Can't locate loadable object for module WWW::Curl in @INC (@INC
>   contains: C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib .) at
>   C:/Perl64/site/lib/WWW/Curl.pm line 11. BEGIN failed--compilation
>   aborted at C:/Perl64/site/lib/WWW/Curl.pm line 11. Compilation failed
>   in require at C:/Perl64/site/lib/WWW/Curl/Easy.pm line 9. Compilation
>   failed in require at C:/Perl64/site/lib/LWP/Curl.pm line 5. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at C:/Perl64/site/lib/LWP/Curl.pm line 5.
>   Compilation failed in require at D:\Varsha\Curl.pl line 1. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at D:\Varsha\Curl.pl line 1.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I am sure that `WWW::Curl` hasn't been installed properly. If I try it myself I get the message `Sorry, no automated install is available on Windows, please see the  file on instructions for a manual install.` Did you read `README.Win32`? It says that you have to edit `Makefile.PL`, and have curl already installed

Comment: is `curl` required? doesn't `LWP::Simple`'s get() do the same? Maybe you have a special reason for using curl, but just thought I'd point out that `LWP::Simple`, or `LWP::UserAgent` should be all you need.

Comment: @Borodin I did manually install Curl after following the instructions in the Readme file. I am also pretty sure this is some path/installation problem. Will try it out again !

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the direction you want to go, but I'd advise you to consider upgrading your perl and changing distributions:

- Install [`Strawberry Perl`](http://strawberryperl.com/) -  5.18.2.2 is the currently recommended version.
- Install [`cpanm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/App%3a%3acpanminus): `perl -MCPAN -e "install App::cpanminus"`
- Install [`LWP::Curl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP%3a%3aCurl): `cpanm LWP::Curl`

I won't bother trying convince you of the change, but `Strawberry Perl` and `cpanm` in combination make installing modules a lot easier than having to dealing with the proprietary ppm's of `ActivePerl` in my opinion.

Just something to consider if you ever get tired of the occasional headaches.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `WWW::Curl` is either not installed or its path is not searchable (it's not in @INC). So the solutions are

1. Make sure that the module is installed.
2. Add the path where the module is installed to the @INC. Since you are on Windows, you can use `set PERL5LIB = c:\path\to\dir`

For a permanent solution follow the below:

Right-click **My Computer** and click **Properties**.

In the **System Properties** window, click on the **Advanced** tab.

In the Advanced section, click the **Environment Variables** button.

In the Environment Variables window in the "**User variables for Foo Bar**" section click on New and type in the following:

Variable name: **PERL5LIB**

Variable value: **c:\path\to\dir**

Then click OK 3 times. Windows that you open after this will already know about the new variable. Type this in the command window, to see the newly set value:

```
echo %PERL5LIB%
```

This will add the private /home/foobar/code directory (or c:\path\to\dir directory) to the beginning of @INC for every script that is executed in the same environment.

Also see: [Installing perl dependency automatically in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066907/installing-perl-dependency-automatically-in-perl/14067234#14067234)