# Error in Bioperl program execution

Tags: algorithm, perl, bioinformatics, bioperl, clustal

I have installed bioperl but confused where to get it and where to run the bioperl program.Then I have tested for it and it was successful
I have run a program for multiple seq. alignment.

Generated an error

> Can't locate Bio/Tools/Run/Alignment/Clustalw.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at msa.pl line 3.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at msa.pl line 3.

Comment: I suggest you provide more details concerning how you installed it and what operating system you are using.

Comment: Yes .. I hv installed thorough CPAN  http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/Installing_BioPerl_on_Ubuntu_Server and am using Ubuntu 12.04LS and it contains perl 5.14.2 in default

Comment: Bio::Tools::Run::Alignment::Clustalw is not part of BioPerl, that is why it can't be located. That module is part of the BioPerl-Run package, so that is what you need installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means that the [Bio::Tools::Run::Alignment::Clustalw](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio::Tools::Run::Alignment::Clustalw) module is missing. You need to install it. Use `cpan Bio::Tools::Run::Alignment::Clustalw` to install it.

Also see: [Installing perl dependency automatically in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066907/installing-perl-dependency-automatically-in-perl/14067234#14067234)